# What is the purpose of boolean switch statements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, if-statement, switch-statement

I just encountered a boolean switch statement in someone else's JavaScript code. It looked a little bit like this:

```
switch (a || b) {
  case true:
    // do some stuff
  break;
  default:
    // do other stuff
  break;
}
```

I haven't been programming for very long, but I certainly have never seen anything like this before. It seems kind of stupid, but I would like to give the programmer the benefit of the doubt. Is there any functional difference between the above code and the following:

```
if (a || b) {
  // do some stuff
}
else {
  // do other stuff
}
```

And if there is, what is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference.  Taking your example into account,

```
var a = 0,
    b = 1;
```

Now let's look at the `switch` statement:

```
switch (a || b) {
```

When this switch statement is run, the expression `a || b` is evaluated.  `||` is a short-circuit operator, it will return the left operand's value if it's "truthy", else it will return the right operand's value.  In this case, `a = 0`, so `b` will be returned (`1`).  Now look at the `case` statement:

```
case true:
```

When evaluating `case` statements, no type coercion is performed on either value and strict equality is assumed.  In our example, this is the same as writing `1 === true`, so the code following the `case` statement is never run.  So let's take a look at the `if` statement:

```
if (a || b) {
```

For an `if` statement, the conditional expression `a || b` is evaluated **and then the result is converted to a boolean**.  Internally, this looks like `ToBoolean(a || b)`.  Since `a || b` evaluates to `1` and coercion of `1` to a boolean is `true`, the condition passes and the block executes.

A better equivalent would be:

```
if ((a || b) === true) {
    // do some stuff
}
else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

*As already pointed out*, in situations where there are many cases and types could vary, a `switch` statement could be useful.  Such a situation would be rare, however.

Comment: @thismax: np, glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2):

To be clear this case looks abusive, but since Javascript isn't strongly typed in principle it can be valuable where you can't control the input:

```
switch (foo)
{
    case true:
        // whatever
        break;
    case false:
        // whatever
        break;
    default:
        // FOO IS NOT A BOOLEAN, DO SOMETHING ELSE!
        break;
}
```

As well as Andrew's mixed case. This is a bit safer than a simple if/else, and more concise than some kind of boolean checking and then an if/else.

Comment: Works because of the lack of coercion on cases as Andy E more eloquently made clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated after Andy's comment and answer**
<strike>There's no difference (in your example), but in your example, the `if` block is more readable and makes more sense in that case (in my opinion).</strike>

<strike>`switch`ing on a statement that evaluates to a `boolean` seems wrong just because there will always only be two cases (`true` and `false`), and for this reason I'd recommend the `if` block instead.</strike>

`switch` makes more sense when you're evaluating a variable that could have many values:

```
switch(fruitType) {
    case 'Apple':
    // Apple Code
    break;
    case 'Orange':
    // Orange Code
    break;
    // etc...
    default: // other fruit
    break;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: There is a difference.  `||` is a short-circuit operator, it will not necessarily return a boolean.  For instance `0 || 1` will return `1`, and case statements operate on strict equality.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is no difference. But depending on how `a` and `b` is defined, you could add more switch statements later on, f.ex:

```
var a = false, b = null;
switch (a || b) {
  case true:
    // do some stuff
  break;
  case null:
    // do some stuff
  break;
  default:
    // do other stuff
  break;
}
```

Other than that, it's mostly a matter of coding preference.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't show it, but I think that this may make for more concise code if you want to use a fallthrough (ie, no break) in the first `case`, depending on the situation.

It also may be a decent construct if you are implementing something in a way that anticipates potential changes and want to have minimal rework (eg, want to keep the actions the same while just redoing the selection logic).